# How to parse json array in android with no name?

Tags: java, android, json

How can I parse an json array in android looking like:

```
["BHUBANESWAR","BANGALORE CANT","BRAHMAPUR","VISAKHAPATNAM",
"VIJAYAWADA ROAD","ASOKHAR","CHAURAKHERI","BANIHAL","SADURA","ANANTNAG",
"PANJGAM","AWANTIPURA","KAKAPORA","PAMPORE"]
```

What I am trying is:

```
     try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);

            JSONArray jsonArray = json.names();

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonArray.getInt(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I am not getting any output.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't getting an exception for every item because you are trying to coerce a String to an int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this...

```
try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length();i++) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonArray.getString(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ to know about difference between JsonArray and JsonObject

Answer (score 2):

uday's answer is right, let me offer some more detailed explanation o that.

JSON offers two basic data structures: **Object** and **Array**.

**Object** is formatted like this:

```
"name":{value(s)}
```

Value(s) may be another Object, an Array or just some data.

**Array**, on the other hand, is formatted like this:

```
[{value}, {value}, {value}...]
```

Again, value may be an Object, another array or, as in your example, a simple piece of data.

Your error happened because you assumed that the data you receive is an object with an array inside. However, it was actually an **anonymous array**, which means you can not parse into an `JSONObject` first, you need to use `JSONArray` right from the beginning.

So this is an anonymous array:

```
["BHUBANESWAR","BANGALORE CANT","BRAHMAPUR","VISAKHAPATNAM",
"VIJAYAWADA ROAD","ASOKHAR","CHAURAKHERI","BANIHAL","SADURA","ANANTNAG",
"PANJGAM","AWANTIPURA","KAKAPORA","PAMPORE"]
```

And if it was an object (called, for example, *myArray*), it would look like this:

```
"myArray":["BHUBANESWAR","BANGALORE CANT","BRAHMAPUR","VISAKHAPATNAM",
"VIJAYAWADA ROAD","ASOKHAR","CHAURAKHERI","BANIHAL","SADURA","ANANTNAG",
"PANJGAM","AWANTIPURA","KAKAPORA","PAMPORE"]
```

The difference is very little (just the `"myArray":` part) but it must nevertheless be parsed in the right way, or else the parser will fail.